# IntelliJ Idea: How to automatically remove commented out code?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, static-analysis

I've run SonarQube analysis on my Android/Java project and it resulted, among others, with issues:

> Sections of code should not be "commented out"

If SonarQube is [able to identify](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:CommentedOutCodeLine) them, is it possible to automatically commented out code in Android Studio? I can't just remove all comments, because there are also some that are legit.

I have 500+ of them and don't want to do it manually. Any ideas?

Comment: So you're wanting to automatically remove some, *but not all*, commented code from your project?

Comment: No, I'd like to remove all commented lines which are _commented out executable code_. I want to keep commented lines which are javadocs, notes, descriptions etc. SonarQube somehow can tell which is which.

Comment: Anyone has this problem before and came up with solution?

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to delete commented code in Android Studio?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't come up with any out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general solution for issues reported by SonarQube since SonarQube only *finds* problems, it doesn't offer a way to *fix* them.

In this particular case of commented out code, the same check is available directly in IntelliJ.

- from the menu, select "Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name"
- type "commented" to select the inspection about commented code
- run it on the whole project

This inspection now lists the occurrences, and the Problems tool window offers you to fix all of them at once.